# Naming group of beans with same Name

Tags: java, spring

Is there any way in spring to name group of beans with same name.For example i have Beans A,B,C,D,E.I should be able to load beans A,B,C with name group1 and load beans D,E with name group2.

Comment: maybe you can create a bean group1 that inject the others bean and then load it? what is the objectif?

Comment: why do you want to do it? Are there a reason? Or is it just to call many bean with a single entry?

Comment: i need it as there will be multiple impl of a interface.I should be able to load different combinations with single name

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which interface implementation is loaded by adding `@Qualifier("mySpecialImplementation")` to your `@Autowire` field. Your implementation therefore needs to be marked with `@Component("mySpecialImplementation")`.

So basically you are assigning an unique (String) identifier to your concrete implementations. To load a special implementation, specify its ID by the Qualifier annotation.

If you really need to load a "group" of beans: Just create a new "group-bean" that contains auto wired fields for all beans to load within this group. If you now inject your new "group-bean", all other beans within the group will also be loaded.

Example:

```
@Service
class Group1 {
   @Autowired
   private A a;
   @Autowired
   private B b;
   @Autowired
   private C c;
   ...
}

@Service
class Group2 {
   @Autowired
   private D d;
   @Autowired
   private E e;
   ...
}
```

Load it by

```
@Autowired
Group1 group1;
```

If you really need to load a list, and not some kind of predefined group:

```
@Autowire
ApplicationContext context;

List<Object> loadBeanGroup(List<String> beanNames){
    List<Object> result = new LinkedList<>();
    for(String name: beanNames){
        result.add(context.getBean(name));
    }
    return result;
}
```

So you basically can define a list of strings with bean names (your group). And load all beans within the list.

Comment: i need multiple beans to be loaded like a iist

Comment: That's exactly what I described above. Let me clarify the solution by a code example. I'll edit my post.

Comment: here it is not dynamic..in my case it should be more dynamic.Like autowiring a map

Comment: The most dynamic way possible is described within the last code block in my post.

Comment: still in loadBeanList its expecting list of bean name not name of group of beans.is there any thing we can get by passing group name

Comment: That's just a matter of where you define your groups. What about annotating your classes with a custom annotation `@GroupName("group1")`. You are then able to create the list of beanNames by simply retrieving all beans annotated with the corresponding group name.